# Android Connection to php web services

Tags: php, android, connection, android-webservice

I am new to android development.  I have a module where I need to connect to a webservice via an android application.  I have the web services in my localhost.

My question is: How to access them from my android application?

Tutorials on web says how to access the live web services.

Comment: if the device and the webservices share common internet, you can use the IP Address of your system to access your webservices

Comment: or if you want, there are many free PHP webservices hosting sites available on internet. Try one of them

Answer (score 0):

- First, both your computer and android device need to be in the same network,
- If you use windows, go to cmd and type ipconfig /all
- Find your computer's ip address
- Then you will be able to access your server's from its ip address.
- You can also check your firewall configuration if steps above don't work

Answer (score 0):

i have did this before ,first of all , if you need to connect your android application with php service at localhost.following thing need following thing

1. Android Emulator on which application install
2. For SERVER -- WAMP or XAMP Server install on Local machine on which you are testing .

now host your php service in the www folder (in case of WAMP) or in the htdocs folder( in case of XAMP).

**Now how to communicate between web service and android :** as describe below

Now you have Envoirnment set now all you have to do is to follow this tutorial it will definatly resolve your issue .
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/